# дайте идею как решать алгоритмическую задачу. по возможности, помогите найти ошибку в моем решении

Tags: python, алгоритм

данна задача:
Вы играете в интересную стратегию. У вашего соперника остались всего одна казарма — здание, в котором постоянно появляются новые солдаты. Перед атакой у вас есть x солдат. За один раунд каждый солдат может убить одного из солдат противника или нанести 1 очко урона казарме (вычесть единицу здоровья у казармы). Изначально у вашего оппонента нет солдат. Тем не менее, его казарма имеет y единиц здоровья и производит p солдат за раунд.

Ход одного раунда:

1.Каждый солдат из вашей армии либо убивает одного из солдат вашего противника, либо наносит 1 очко урона казарме. Каждый солдат может выбрать своё действие. Когда казарма теряет все свои единицы здоровья, она разрушается.
2.Ваш противник атакует. Он убьет k ваших солдат, где k — количество оставшихся у противника солдат.
3.Если казармы еще не разрушены, ваш противник производит p новых солдат.
Ваша задача — разрушить казарму и убить всех солдат противника. Если это возможно, посчитайте минимальное количество раундов, которое вам нужно для этого. В противном случае выведите -1.

Формат ввода
На вход подаётся три целых числа x, y, p (1 ≤ x, y, p ≤ 5000) — количество ваших солдат на старте игры, количество очков здоровья казармы и количество производимых за раунд казармой солдат, соответственно. Каждое число расположено в новой строке.

Формат вывода
Если возможно убить всех вражеских солдат и разрушить казарму, выведите минимальное количество раундов, необходимых для этого. В противном случае выведите -1.

```
Пример 1
Ввод    
10
11
15
Вывод
4
|
Пример 2
Ввод
1
2
1
Вывод
-1
|
Пример 3
Ввод
1
1
1
Вывод
1
|
Пример 4
Ввод
25
200
10
Вывод
13
```

меня хватило только на самое тривиальное решение, которое не прошло по всем тестам. и методом тыка я так и не смог найти ошибочные входные данные. подскажите правильный алгоритм решения, или может хотя бы общую идею, чтобы переписать код.

мое не проходящее по всем тестам решение:

```
def f(x, y, p):
if x > p:
    overhit = x - p
    return (y + overhit - 1 - x) // overhit + 1
army = 0
move_num = 0
while x < y and x > 0:
    move_num += 1
    y -= x
    x -= army
    army += p
if y > 0:
    move_num += 1
    overhit = x - y
    army -= overhit
    x -= army
while x > 0 and army > 0:
    move_num += 1
    army -= x
    x -= army
return move_num if army <= 0 else -1
```

`x, y, p = map(int, input().split()) print(f(x, y, p))`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание вашего решения. Как именно программа решает что делать солдатам?

Comment: В зависимости от того, какие входные данные, возможны минимум три различные стратегии. Ну или по-русски - прежде чем писать программу, решите задачу "на бумажке".

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, такое решение

```
def f(x, y, p):
c = 0
#print("x,y,p,c")
while True:
    c += 1
    x -= p
    y -= 1
    p += 1
    #print(x, y, p, c)
    if x <= 0:
        print("-1 (Enemy win!)")
        print(f"Number of step {c}")
        break
    if y <= 0:
        x = x
        p = p
        y = 0
        c = c
        #print("1.2")
        break

while x > 0:
    c += 1
    x -= p
    p -= 1
    #print(x, y, p, c)
    if x <= 0:
        print("-1 (Enemy win!)")
        print(f"Number of step {c}")
        break
    if p <= 0:
        print("1 (You WIN!!!)")
        print(f"Number of step {c}")
        break
        
            
f(122, 10, 1)
# You should know that for win: x = (y + p)^2 + 1
```